# Using a javascript variable when setting virtual page views in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to send a virtual page view to Google Analytics by setting the page before the pageview sends. I've tested my code in the console, but it sends differently to analytics.

```
 var virtualPage= window.location.pathname + queryString;

 lpScriptVersion = '1.3.0';

 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function()  {
 (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();
 a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;
 a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})     
 (window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');;

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
  ga('set', 'page', virtualPage);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

When I put the variable virtualPage into the console, I get this:

```
 "/test/?variable1=testa&variable2=testa&variable3=testa"
```

When I look in analytics, I see this:

```
 "/test/?variable2=testa&variable3=testa"
```

I'm not sure where the first variable is going. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What gets logged to the console when you use the [analytics.js debugger](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/debugging)?

Comment: Nothing out of the usual. I don't see the page value, however. Maybe I'm not sure what to look for?

Comment: It will show you exactly what it's sending to Google Analytics, so you can determine if the problem is on your end or on their end. Is this page hosted anywhere online?

Comment: It turns out the variable we were using (utm_campaign) is automatically stripped out by analytics since it is one of their variables. It will automatically strip out the other campaign variable as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, next time don't change the names of variables you use. If you'd said it was `utm_campaign`, I would have immediately known what was happening :)